# Stop code but continue executing future methods

Tags: apex, future

I want to stop the execution of my application but allowing only the @future methods to continue to run.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: what do you mean "stop execution"? Down Salesforce servers?

Comment: Well, I want to end the execution of my createUser method and whatever comes after that but still keeping my @future methods to continue running. Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: @future methods are Asynchronous meaning they don't occur in the same context. Their execution is delayed to some point in the near future.  Simply `return`ing out of your code early will prevent the rest of your code from executing, any scheduled @future methods already executed will continue to run.

Comment: what is your issue? I really doubt you need to stop execution

Comment: I needed to save the real information about a user U that I couldn't return trough createUser because of the error related to updating user and person account objects at the same time. I wanted the @future call to do the saving of this data with some small modifications to avoid conflicts. Thanks

Comment: @JoseCabreraZuniga Did you try including some return statements?

Comment: could this create another transaction to force @future methods to execute?... interesting thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want to bail out of a specific *method*, you can just use a `return` statement. Examples:

```
public static void myMethod1()
{
    myFutureMethod();
    if (conditionToStop) return;
}
public static String myMethod2()
{
    myFutureMethod();
    if (conditionToStop) return null;
}
```

Neither of these approaches will cancel your `@future` call.